# What is the compile time type of this? (in Java)

Tags: java, design-patterns

I suspect it is the type of the class in which it is written but I am not 100% sure, could someone please confirm my suspicion and perhaps give a reference to Java Language Specification where this behaviour is defined?

Let's say class `A` has a method `a()` which uses the `this` keyword in its body, and class `B` extends class `A`. Now class `B` has inherited method `a()`, however, I am not sure if the compile time type of `this` in `B.a()` is now `A` or `B` ?

I am asking this because I am trying to understand how the visitor pattern works, as it is described in this Robert C. Martin's [Visitor chapter](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~horton/cs4240/slides/files/visitor.pdf) from *The Principles, Patterns, and Practices of Agile Software Development*.

It seems to be crucial to know the compile time type of `this` if one wants to fully understand the visitor pattern because overloaded method calls are resolved at compile time. More specifically, I refer to the compile time type of `this` in the `accept` methods in the visitor pattern.

Comment: In a method of class B, `this` is a reference to an object of class B.  If, however, one is in a method of class A that is inherited by B, `this` references an A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of `this` is the type of the class in which it is used. In fact, it is crucial for the visitor pattern from the article to work.

Visitor pattern implements double dispatch in two steps - selecting the appropriate `accept` method in the object being visited (first leg), and then selecting the appropriate `visit` method in the visitor (second leg). The first leg is implemented through *overriding*; the second leg is implemented through *overloading*.

Note that it is not necessary to use overloading for the second leg. In fact, it is common not to use it there for better readability. Compare these two implementations:

```
// Copied from Listing 29-2
public interface ModemVisitorOverload
{
    void visit(HayesModem modem);
    void visit(ZoomModem modem);
    void visit(ErnieModem modem);
}

public interface ModemVisitorNoOverload
{
    void visitHayes(HayesModem modem);
    void visitZoom(ZoomModem modem);
    void visitErnie(ErnieModem modem);
}
```

The second implementation is not using the overloading. It works in exactly the same way, except human readers of the code immediately see what is going on.

Comment: By your argument all overloading is less readable then adding argtype to name and violating DRY, no?

Comment: @MiserableVariable There is no repeating one way or the other - in both cases the methods are completely separate from each other. The type of the object being visited is essential to what each of the `visitXyz` method does. In fact, it's not always the name of the type that gets appended.

Comment: @MiserableVariable Separate method names make the Visitor pattern much easier to understand.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight can you point me an example of where something besides the type name is embedded in the method name? If the type name is embedded, do you agree it violates DRY and is equivalent to un-overloading any other set of overloaded methods?

Comment: @MiserableVariable In my (proprietary) code for a library that processes expressions I un-overloaded the `visit` methods by lining up their names with the syntax of my expressions, rather than with the names of types in the expression tree, for example, `visitDotExpression(MemberAccessExpression e)`. As far as the second part of the question goes, I do not agree with the premise of the question that the DRY principle should be even considered in the context of method overloading, even when we are not talking the visitor pattern.

Answer (score 3):

`this` is a reference to the current object and as the JLS [15.8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3) states

> The type of `this` is the class C within which the keyword `this` occurs.
>
> At run time, the class of the actual object referred to may be the class C or any subclass of C.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the answers.

After reading the answers I got inspired to try to compile the code below. The result of this little experiment might give also some insight into the answer to the original question.

**The code below does not compile** because `this` in A is not the correct type (according to the compiler). So for the visitor pattern to work the `accept` method needs to be repeated in subclasses of `A` and the methods called by `v.visit(this)` are fixed already at compile time (as others have pointed out already in their answers).

The point of the original question was whether one could avoid this redundancy in code but it seems not.

```
class A{
    void a(VisitorI v){v.visit(this);}
}

class B1 extends A{}
class B2 extends A{}

interface VisitorI{
    void visit(B1 b1);
    void visit(B2 b2);
}

class Visitor implements VisitorI{
    public void visit(B1 b1){
        System.out.print("b1");
    }

    public void visit(B2 b2){
        System.out.print("b2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as `B.a`. There is only one method here and that is in class A, so `this` obviously has the static type of A. This isn't C++ where function bodies get duplicated willy nilly (if you use templates).

Now if you created a method named `a` inside of class B, then `this` would have the static type of B inside that method. And thanks to the magic of virtual methods, it would get called based on the runtime type when you invoke `.a()` on an object that could be either type A or B. But this is onyl if you override A's method.

Comment: The "this" used in A.a() (=super.a()) will still have the compile-time type A. "this" used in B will have B as the compile-time type. And of course both will have type B during runtime, if an instance of B is used.

Answer (score -2):

An instance of an Object can only have one type. In the case of an instance of `B extends A` then `this` will always be a `B`, even inside methods of `A`.

However you can always use an object of type `B` as thought it is an an object of type `A` so even though `getClass` will return a `B` all the methods within `A` can use `this` as though it were a `A`.

For example its completely valid to do:

```
 A a = new B(); // Valid as B extends A
 a.test();
```

If `B` declares a method `test()` then that version of the method will be called, even though you are referring to it as though it were an `A`.

This is also how things like over-riding methods can be used to change the behavior of a base class from a sub class. When you have a method `test()` in `A`, and then override the method in `B` then whenever code in `A` calls `this.test()` it will actually call the over-ridden method in `B`.

Your mistake comes from the assumption that Overriding is resolved at compile time. It's not, it's resolved at run time Over *load* ed methods are resolved at compile time. Over *ride* n methods are resolved at run time. Overloading and Overriding are very different things.

Comment: The compile time type of `this` is based on where it appears.  Even though `foo` in the following can be called "from" an instance of `B` (e.g., `B b = ...; b.foo();`, the `this` in `foo` has the type `A`. ``class A { public void foo() { /* `this` is an a */ } } class B { public void bar() { /* `this` is a b */ } }``.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Yes, that's what I said. Clearly some people found it confusing as it has 2 downvotes but what I said is correct :s I'll try and reword

Comment: I assumed that by "`this` will always be an A, even inside methods of B." you meant that `this`, inside a method defined in `B`, would have type `A`, and that's not correct.  (It can be tricky to word these things, though, so it's an easy area to know the correct answer, but to write something misleading. :))

Comment: Also, in OP's question `B extends A`.  It's unnecessarily confusing to switch to `A extends B` in your answer…

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor hmm, good point. Flipped them back (hopefully didn't miss any).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor If B extends A and a method in A calls this.getClass() then if you call that method in an instance of B you will see B. If you call it in an instance of A you will see A.

Comment: Yes, the actual *value* of `this` is a `B` (or some subclass of `B`, etc.), but that's not the _compile time type_ of `this`.  Even if you declare `class B extends A { void doBStuff() { ... } }` you still can't compile `class A { void doStuff { this.doBStuff(); } }`, because you don't know that any particular `A` will actually be a `B`.  The question was about the type used by the compiler;  I don't think there was much question about the class of the object ­— there's just one object, and it's not changing.  The question is just about what the compiler can know about it at compile time.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Yes, but the question is also about overriding (I know he says overloading but I'm fairly sure he means overriding) - which is effected by the fact that this is actually either an A or a B as it is resolved at run time. I've added a paragraph on that as well...